# Transport error in WebSocket client :No enum constant org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand.Hello from the server!Server says: CONNECT

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have a Springboot WebSocket Server application running on `ws:localhost:8080/websocket`. I developed a Springboot WebSocket client application which must be able to connect to the server and send messages. But am getting `Transport error in WebSocket client session: No enum constant org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand.Hello from the server!Server says: CONNECT" error (ilegalArgumentException)` in the client application that I have developed. Below is the code.

The Main Class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FinalClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FinalClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketStompClient webSocketStompClient() {
        return new WebSocketStompClient(new StandardWebSocketClient());
    }
}
```

The controller:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.example.final_client.models.Message;
import com.example.final_client.services.WebSocketClientService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/websocket")
public class WebSocketClientController {

    private final WebSocketClientService webSocketClientService;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketClientController(WebSocketClientService webSocketClientService) {
        this.webSocketClientService = webSocketClientService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/connect")
    public ResponseEntity<String> connectToServer() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        webSocketClientService.connectToServer();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Connected to WebSocket server", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/subscribe/{topicName}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> subscribeToTopic(@PathVariable String topicName) {
        webSocketClientService.subscribeToTopic(topicName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Subscribed to topic: " + topicName, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/send/{topicName}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessageToServer(@PathVariable String topicName, @RequestBody Message message) {
        webSocketClientService.sendMessageToServer(message, topicName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Message sent to topic: " + topicName, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The config class:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;

import com.example.final_client.util.MyStompSessionHandler;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskSchedulerreturn() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketStompClient webSocketStompClientret() {
        WebSocketStompClient client = new WebSocketStompClient(new StandardWebSocketClient());
        client.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        client.setTaskScheduler(taskSchedulerreturn());
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public StompSessionHandler stompSessionHandler() {
        return new MyStompSessionHandler();
    }
}
```

The Service class:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;

import com.example.final_client.models.Message;
import com.example.final_client.util.MyStompSessionHandler;

@Service
public class WebSocketClientService {
    private final String serverUri = "ws://localhost:8080/websocket";
    private StompSession stompSession;

    private final MessageConverter messageConverter;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketClientService() {
        this.messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        ;
    }

    public void connectToServer() {
        WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);

        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        CompletableFuture<StompSession> connection = stompClient.connectAsync(serverUri, sessionHandler);
        try {
            stompSession = connection.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
    }

    public void subscribeToTopic(String topicName) {
        if (stompSession != null) {
            String destination = "/topic/" + topicName;
            stompSession.subscribe(destination, new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                    if (payload instanceof Message) {
                        Message message = (Message) payload;
                        System.out.println("Received message from topic " + topicName + ": " + message.getContent());
                    }
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Subscribed to topic: " + topicName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not connected to the server. Please call connectToServer() first.");
        }
    }

    public void sendMessageToServer(Message message, String topicName) {
        if (stompSession != null) {
            String destination = "/app/sendMessage/" + topicName;
            stompSession.send(destination, message);
            System.out.println("Sent message to topic " + topicName + ": " + message.getContent());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not connected to the server. Please call connectToServer() first.");
        }
    }
}
```

The Handler class:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompFrameHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;

public class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        System.out.println("Connected to WebSocket server");
        session.subscribe("/topic", new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                return String.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                String message = (String) payload;
                System.out.println("Received message from server: " + message);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {

        if (payload instanceof byte[]) {
            String message = new String((byte[]) payload);
            System.out.println("Recived message: " + message);
        } else if (payload instanceof String) {
            String topicName = (String) payload;
            System.out.println("Recived topic name: " + topicName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Received unknown payload: " + payload);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload,
            Throwable exception) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred in WebSocket session: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
        System.err.println("Transport error in WebSocket client session: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please help me with a solution. Thanks in advance

I tried configuring the client but am blocked